# Splitting polygons in OpenLayers is not working

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs, splitting

I have some WFS layers in OpenLayers, containing Polygons. I try to make a tool to split these polygnos and save them to db.

```
//The layer which I want spliting work on
var contract_layer = map.getLayersByName("contracts");
//The spliting control
var split_control = new OpenLayers.Control.Split({
       layer: contract_layer,
       listeners: {
           'beforesplit' : function(){
               alert("before");
           }
       }
});
```

and then I add this control to my map and make it active:

```
toolbarItems.push(new GeoExt.Action({
       control: split_control,
       map: map,
       toggleGroup: 'map'
   }));

   map.addControl(split_control);
   split_control.activate();
```

And now when I chose the tool, I can draw a line which ends with double-click, but that's it. nothing else.Nothing splits and nothing is sent to geoserver. 
What do you think I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think the split control only works against line features, not polygon features. You will need to post the feature (to be split) and split line to a Web Processing Service, or use the jsts library.

Comment: +1. OpenLayers.Control.SplitFeature can't split polygon features, but JSTS can. Here you can find some hints: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jsts-devs/jXZrIa_qwwo